# Can you show a Thank you message after completing a Survey?

Tags: survey-list

Is it possible to add a Thank You page, after completing a survey in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about? [SharePoint: Creating Thank You Pages for Improved User Experience](http://blog.springhouse.com/index.php/2009/05/06/creating-thank-you-pages-for-improved-user-experience/) or [URL Source= for Thank You on Submit](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/url-source-for-thank-you-on-submit.aspx)

Comment: The Host is not resolvable on first URL, second one has an SSL cert problem.  Can't paste any part of the solution here?  Found many others.